# erlang google oauth2 protocol for google calling apis

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, erlang, jwt, erlangweb

Hello I am writing oauth 2 library to access google api's and my code is as follows

```
    jwt_create() ->

    {ok,PemBin} = file:read_file("your-key-file.pem"),
    PemEntry = public_key:pem_decode(PemBin),
    [A,B] = PemEntry,
    io:format("A:: ~p ~n",[A]),
    PrivateKey = public_key:pem_entry_decode(PemEntry),
    JwtHeaderJson = encode_json(jwt_header()),
    JwtClaimsetJson = encode_json(jwt_claimset()),
    ComputeSignature = compute_signature(JwtHeaderJson, JwtClaimsetJson, PrivateKey),
    Z=binary:replace(
      binary:replace(<<JwtHeaderJson/binary, ".", JwtClaimsetJson/binary, ".", ComputeSignature/binary>>,
                     <<"+">>, <<"-">>, [global]),
      <<"/">>, <<"_">>, [global]),
    io:format("JWT:: ~p ~n",[Z]).
compute_signature(Header, ClaimSet,#'RSAPrivateKey'{publicExponent=Exponent

                                                          ,modulus=Modulus

                                                          ,privateExponent=PrivateExponent}) ->
    base64:encode(crypto:sign(rsa, sha256, <<Header/binary, ".", ClaimSet/binary>>, 
            [Exponent, Modulus, PrivateExponent])).
encode_json(JWToken) ->
    base64:encode(jsx:encode(JWToken)).
```

I am getting error as follows:

> exception error: no function clause matching 
>                       public_key:pem_entry_decode([{'PrivateKeyInfo',<<48,130,4,191,2,1,0,48,13,6,9,42,134,
>                                                                        72,134,247,13,1,1,1,5,0,4,130,4,...>>,
>                                                                      not_encrypted},
>                                                    {'Certificate',<<48,130,3,96,48,130,2,72,160,3,2,1,2,2,8,
>                                                                     79,59,244,35,60,15,3,155,48,...>>,
>                                                                   not_encrypted}]) (public_key.erl, line 123)
>        in function  googleoauth:jwt_create/0 (src/googleoauth.erl, line 55)

Please help me in generating JWS and JWT for OAUTH 2 for accessing google apis

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the wrong thing to public_key:pem_entry_decode/1:

This will resolve your problem:

```
PrivateKey = public_key:pem_entry_decode(A),
```

public_key:pem_entry_decode/1 takes a single pem_entry() but a PEM file can contain many entries, perhaps your code `PemEntry = public_key:pem_decode(PemBin)` should read `PemEntries = public_key:pem_decode(PemBin)` instead?

Also note the line before assumes 2 list entries, you might have meant this instead (not sure your intent here though)?

```
[A|B] = PemEntry,
```